# jQuery UI removeClass showing no animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table row displayed which should be highlighted for a short moment. To do this i have this piece of code using `jQuery UI functions`:

```
$('tr#' + currentlyAdded).addClass("highlighted", 600, "easeInQuad", function () {
    $('tr#' + currentlyAdded).removeClass("highlighted", 1500, "linear");
});
```

So i add the class `highlighted` with the specified easing, which works perfectly fine. After that i expect the class to be removed with such an animation, but however it just disappears no matter which time or easing i specify. Elsewhere in the code i tested the functionality of `removeClass()` and it seems to work generally like i expect it.

Is there a problem using `removeClass` in the callback of addClass or what is causing the problem here?

**Edit:** Table structure:

```
<div class="jumbotron content">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-12" id="no-more-tables">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Vorname</th>
                        <th>Nr.</th>
                        <th>Aktionen</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="emp_table">
                    <tr id="8b08e40a-0e59-47e7-bb05-fa6626e998d8" onclick="onListClick(this,id);">
                        <td><img src="/Content/pic/Person1.jpg" width="64"></td>
                        <td data-title="Name">Name</td>
                        <td data-title="Vorname">Vorname</td>
                        <td data-title="Nr.">000013</td>
                        <td data-title="Aktionen"> <input id="0" class="fb8" type="button" value="Edit" onclick="showDetails(id);"> </td>
                    </tr>
```

As you may see i'm using bootstrap here. So only css i specify is this:

`highlighted` class:

```
.highlighted{
    background-color:#fe9a2e!important;
}
```

Using important here because the `jumbotron` class would override my `tr`.

**Edit 2:**

I created a fiddle to reproduce the error but somehow it works here. So I found that someone edited the `bootstrap.min.css` file, so that these styles like different row colors within `jumbotron` for odd and even appear. But knowing this i still can't figure out why that isn't working. I also tried to test this without the `jumbotron` class but still no success.

**Edit 3:**
Finally got the problem: Since i'm using `!important` for my class, jQuery's animation is never visible. Inspecting the HTML while the `removeClass()` function is working, I could see that it adds `style="background-color:rgb(..)"` to the row which has no effects because of the class.

Comment: It's almost certainly a problem with the placing of your transition in css. Please provide your css

Comment: provide your table structure!

Comment: Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/vz33yk86/7/). Working fine here.

Comment: BTW are you applying class to TR or TD?

Comment: I'm applying it to TR. Until this step it's working fine. Just removing is causing problems because it's not showing the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my edits, the answer to the question is following:

When you are trying to animate a CSS-property which was marked with `!important` the animation of jQuery is actually happening but not visible. So removing the `!important` part will fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more I wouldn't totally know but I'm wondering whether its a potential of the `currentlyAdded` variable maybe getting muddy somewhere?

Possibly change your code to this and see if it has any better result?

```
$('tr#' + currentlyAdded).addClass("highlighted", 600, "easeInQuad", function () {
    $(this).removeClass("highlighted", 1500, "linear");
});
```

Using `$(this)` in the callback should hopefully target the element that has had the class highlighted added to it, even if somehow the variable changes

Comment: Yes, i should be using $(this), but however this won't change much since the class will still be removed without showing any animations.

Comment: I don't see any difference between  `$(this)` and `'tr#' + currentlyAdded`

Comment: If `currentlyAdded` changed before the callback was run, then the element wouldn't be the same element. `$(this)` means that the element that has the class added to it, is the one thats targeted in the callback